# STGeomFromText error 24141: A number is expected at position 27 of the input. The input has ,

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial

Can not find the reason why I can not pass the return value of an User Defined function directly to STGeomFromText. Please help.

```
declare @points nvarchar(max);
set @points = '43.6950681126962,-79.4046143496645,43.6959369175095,-79.3999794923712,43.6946181896527,-79.3994001349161,43.6778911368006,-79.3695525136617,43.6787446722787,-79.3714193302229,43.6760133178263,-79.3941859209041,43.6755011769934,-79.3969110453878,43.6906308086704,-79.4031123121585,43.6950681126962,-79.4046143496645';

/*-----------failed, return error 24141-*/
/*Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry": 
System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 27 of the input. The input has ,.
System.FormatException: 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.RecognizeDouble()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseLineStringText()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParsePolygonText()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWktReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars text, Int32 srid)
*/
select COUNT(*) from  t 
where   geometry::STGeomFromText( dbo.GeoCoordinateInBoundery(@points), 0) .STContains( geometry::STGeomFromText('Point(' + cast(t.Latitude as varchar(32)) + ' ' + 
cast(t.Longitude as varchar(32)) + ')', 0)) = 1

/*----OK-------*/
declare @ss nvarchar(max)
set @ss = dbo.GeoCoordinateInBoundery(@points) 
select COUNT(*) from  t 
where   geometry::STGeomFromText( @ss, 0) .STContains( geometry::STGeomFromText('Point(' + cast(t.Latitude as varchar(32)) + ' ' + 
cast(t.Longitude as varchar(32)) + ')', 0)) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The valid syntax for WKT puts a space between lat and long value pairs and a comma between each coordinate.

So you should have:

```
set @points = '43.6950681126962 -79.4046143496645,43.6959369175095 -79.3999794923712,43.6946181896527 -79.3994001349161,43.6778911368006,-79.3695525136617,43.6787446722787 -79.3714193302229,43.6760133178263 -79.3941859209041,43.6755011769934 -79.3969110453878,43.6906308086704 -79.4031123121585,43.6950681126962 -79.4046143496645';
```

Comment: Thanks. The function GeoCoordinateInBoundery will return the string with the correct format. when I use a variable to hold the return value from the function, then geometry::STGeomFromText runs smoothly without error.

Comment: It didn't answer my question. the variable `@points` has be rewritten to `@ss` which is in correct format.